# Second-order Taylor expansion for Operators

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, operator-theory, approximation, nonlinear-analysis

Let $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ be functions in $C^{\infty}$. Then let $A(u)$ be an operator.

A valid reference mentioned that the second-order Taylor expansion of the operator $A$ is:

$$A(u+v) = A(u) + dA(u)[v] + \int_{0}^{1}(1-\alpha)d^{(2)}A(u + \alpha v)[v]^{2} d\alpha$$

What does the notation $dA(u)[v]$ and $d^{(2)}A(u + \alpha v)[v]^{2}$ mean?

Comment: Presumably it is the first and second (Frechet) derivative of $A$ at $u$ evaluated at $v$ / $v,v$. This looks like the formulation of the Taylor series in a Banach space (with integral remainder).